# How do I unhook WordPress action hook in plugin file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to unhook and modify an action from within my child themes functions.php file.

The WordPress plugin Sensei, adds this action in line 86 of this document.

https://github.com/Automattic/sensei/blob/master/includes/class-sensei-modules.php#L86

The action references a function further down the page that is responsible for outputting a dynamic header element.

```
/**
 * Show the title modules on the single course template.
 *
 * Function is hooked into sensei_single_course_modules_before.
 *
 * @since 1.8.0
 * @return void
 */

public function course_modules_title( ) {
   if( sensei_module_has_lessons() ){
        echo '<header><h2>' . __('Modules', 'woothemes-sensei') . '</h2></header>';
    }
}
```

My goal here is to change the html currently output as 'Modules' to something else.

I have tried to the following in my child themes functions.php file but neither seem to be working.

```
remove_action( 'sensei_single_course_modules_before', array( 'Sensei_Core_Modules', 'course_modules_title' ), 20);

remove_action( 'sensei_single_course_modules_before', array( 'Sensei()->Sensei_Core_Modules', 'course_modules_title' ), 20);
```

The issue is, I do not know how to determine which initial parameter, to add to the array to call the correct class. Because I am accessing it externally I cannot use `$this` like it is being used in the core file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the action you have to find the instance of the class. This is an assumption since I don't have access to the source code of Sensei but big chance there is one since most WordPress plug-ins use this method.

When you find the instance name you can load it using `global $senseiInstance` - replace this with the actual name of the variable.

Then you can remove the action using for example this code:

`remove_action( 'sensei_single_course_modules_before', array( $senseiInstance, 'course_modules_title' ), 20);`

More information can be found in for example this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/digging-deeper-wordpress-hooks-filters.

Hope this helps you out!